# Python class Inheriting from tk.Frame with a list attribute

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I'm in the process of teaching myself tkinter (objected-oriented style).

I want my class to produce a simple window with a single label in it. And I want the text for the label to come from an attribute, the first element of a list. This is a mockup made in Paint of what I would expect the window to look like:

[image]

But when I run the code below I get an error message (`TypeError: create() argument 1 must be str or None, not list`). I can't figure out how to pass 'my_list' so to create an instance of my class.

Thanks for any help!

```
import tkinter as tk

my_list = [222, 333, 444, 555]

class MyWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent,  lst):
        self.lst = lst
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.window_height = 200
        self.window_width = self.window_height * 2 
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=self.window_width, height=self.window_height)
        canvas.pack()  
        label = tk.Label(self, text=str(self.lst[0]))       
        label.pack()
    
root= tk.Tk(my_list)
MyWindow(root).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You want your class generate a window, but your class just inherited from `tk.Frame`.

Comment: `root = tk.Tk()` and `MyWindow(root, my_list).pack()` could run it without exception.But this won't generate a window directly.Your class will create a `frame` and put it on a Window.

Comment: You should not pass `my_list` to `Tk()`.  Should pass it to `MyWindow`: `MyWindow(root, my_list)`.

Comment: ```root``` is inherited from ```Tk()``` class of ```tkinter``` basically we are making a root window (parent/master) on which our UI will be hosted. Upon calling ```MyWindow()``` you have to tell it, that whatever UI components are present in ```MyWindow()``` class are to be hosted on root window or parent or main or master window (whatever you seem as understandable). So Tell mywindow to be the root and pass the my_list like : ```MyWindow(root,my_list)```. About ```tk.Frame```, you are inheriting some of UI components which you want to be hosted on window like button, label etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you cannot pass `my_list` to `tk.Tk()`.

Second, your `MyWindow` requires two parameters: `parent` and `list` (though you should name that second parameter something different).

Third, calling a geometry manager (`pack`, `grid`, or `place`) inline with the creation of the widget is a bad practice that should be avoided.

Here is how the final block of code should look like:

```
root= tk.Tk()
mywindow = MyWindow(root, my_list)
mywindow.pack()
```

This will end up with a window that has the label at the bottom. If you want it at the top, reverse the order that you pack the items in the frame and/or explicitly state where they should go:

```
label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
canvas.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)
```